# best way to split String in java

Tags: java, string, split

I have a String like `"asdfsd[12345]skfjoib[346676]qwoiejflksjv[12345]"`
and I want to split it to an Array like

```
Array[0] = asdfsd
Array[1] = [12345]
Array[2] = skfjoib
Array[3] = [346676]
Array[4] = qwoiejflksjv
Array[5] = [12345]
```

What is the best approach(less code,more speed) to do that ?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) can help you out.

Comment: @LutzHorn yes, but it seems a little clumsy to me . I match the Strings in [] with regex, get it's index, and then split the source String then insert the matcher into the array.

Comment: That looks like an intermediate step towards an end goal - it might be easier to focus on pulling out the text as what it is in your domain and the numbers as numbers (i.e. split and process into the next step in one go instead of populating an intermediate array first). Setting your own delimiters using the Scanner class and using next() & nextInt() might work well to explore the idea.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
input.split("(?=\\[)|(?<=\\])"))
```

The regexp says *"Split on anything preceeding a `[` or following a `]`"*.

Demo:

```
String input = "asdfsd[12345]skfjoib[346676]qwoiejflksjv[12345]";
for (String s : input.split("(?<=\\])|(?=\\[)"))
    System.out.println(s);
```

Output:

```
asdfsd
[12345]
skfjoib
[346676]
qwoiejflksjv
[12345]
```

Comment: This is really a PERFECT solution for me ! Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Very quick 'n dirty:

```
String[] ss = s.replaceAll("[", ";[").replaceAll("]", "];").split(";");
```

Comment: Obviously won't work if the string contains `;` to begin with.